# How does sshuttle actually forward TCP packets? How is it different from a full-fledged VPN?

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, tcp

Here is the scenario:

On **myHost** (1.1.1.1) I run:

```
sshuttle -r user@remoteHost 0/0
```

Now, if I check the my current IP on **myHost** with an http request directed to one of those services that echo your IP, I get the IP of the **remoteHost** 2.2.2.2. Things are similar to this schema:

> **myHost** *---sshTunnel-->* **remoteHost** --------> **whatismyip.com**

ChatGPT has been blocked in Italy. My **remoteHost** has a non-Italian IP (say 2.2.2.2). Just for testing, I tried to open up ChatGPT (now backed by Cloudflare) using such a tunnel, but it returned the block page, as the source IP was an Italian IP. Shouldn't my connection look like it comes from 2.2.2.2 from the ChatGPT perspective?

Interestingly, if I connect with an OpenVPN client from **myHost** to an OpenVPN server running on the same **remoteHost**, everything works fine with ChatGPT. Why does it happen? What are the differences?

Comment: random thought: compare the results of `dig chat.openai.com.` vs `dig +tcp chat.openai.com.` in the normal case, in OpenVPN case and in sshuttle case.

Comment: *"but it returned the block page, __as the source IP was an Italian IP__"* - is this your interpretation or does it explicitly say so?

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich, it does explicitly say so. The strage things is that if check `whatismyip.com` under sshuttle, I do see 2.2.2.2 not 1.1.1.1

Comment: @floatingpurr: does it say which IP address it sees? Note that ChatGPT is reachable by both IPv4 and IPv6 and the latter one is usually the one a system picks if it has IPv6 connectivity. Or it might simply not use TCP in the first place but HTTP/3 (which is UDP). See [issue#671](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/issues/671), [issue#595](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/issues/595) and [issue#574](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/issues/574). I suggest to use tcpdump or wireshark to actually look at the traffic to understand what is going on.

Comment: @A.B, they look identical in all the cases. chat.openai.com CNAME chat.openai.com.cdn.cloudflare.net / chat.openai.com.cdn.cloudflare.net A 104.18.2.161 / chat.openai.com.cdn.cloudflare.net A 104.18.3.161

Comment: @floatingpurr my random thought was as Steffen Ullrich wrote that sshuttle doesn't tunnel UDP (unless a very specific Linux tproxy setup is used, which doesn't appear trivial), but if DNS isn't involved, yes traffic itself must not use UDP either, and you have to ensure that (TCP) IPv6 is tunneled too. I had checked UDP behavior with `dig` and tcpdump (as Steffen Ullrich already suggested).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich no, it just returns the Ray ID +[Geo:IT]. What is not completely clear to me is if sshuttle on **remoteHost** changes the source IP in the IP packet before forwarding it to the internet. I guess yes, otherwise it can't receive back the response and return it back to **myHost**

Comment: [Cont'ed] I mean: isn't sshuttle (and ssh tunneling) supposed to do something like [this](https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:4800/0*X9ylouL2AO0E3VZb)? ([source](https://zicodeng.medium.com/how-vpn-works-b7549dcc6ce4))

Comment: @floatingpurr: Like with all VPN (and similar) the traffic has only the source IP of the VPN exit if it actually enters the VPN in the first place. And the use of IPv6 or UDP instead of  TCP might a reason for not doing this. But this is not known from the details you provide. So again, do a traffic capture to see what actually happens.